# webpack proxy with more than one endpoint

Tags: webpack

I am trying to set up the webpack proxy of the devserver to proxy routes of `/api/*` and `/auth/*`.

I have so far I have it set up like this:

```
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(ROOT_PATH, 'build'),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    progress: true,
    port: '4040',
    proxy: {
    '/auth/*': 'http://localhost:5000/'
    }
```

BUt it obviously only allows `/auth/*`.

I want something like this;

`/(auth|api)/*` but I don't know if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using [http-proxy-middleware](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#http-proxy-middleware-options)
something like this:

```
proxy(['/api', '/ajax', '/someotherpath'], {...})
```